# Zoom option on my product pages - magento

Tags: products, zoom

I have zoom option on my product page, but when its clicked it hangs the website - i checked on other PCs and its the same scenario

Also I am also not getting the 2 tiny pics which use to come earlier below the product image.  The "Exclude" in the db is '0' for all products.

product page example :-
http://justfrompound.com/root-catalog/default-category/wood-thermometer.html

Answer (score 1):

There are some JS Errors in Frontend. Try to fix them. This will probably solve your zoom.

And your smaller images have CSS-Attribute: `display:none`

Comment: thx kevin, havent changed any js scripts - not a pro at js, do u reckon if i restore the backup to sort this issue.  Where exactly this CSS-attribute can  be sorted ? thx.

Comment: I don't know your code.
It seems you're using some 3rd party plugin for your image zoom. 
Maybe you could deactivate this for testing. 

The CSS-Attribute might be correct - there could be a JS that toggles visibility.

If you have access to an older backup of your shop, you could diff your theme-files.

Comment: The error coming past 2 days, the last i ammended was dashboard.phtml and added google conversion code in it, which i reckon has got nothing to do with the product zooming error.  i have checked the files on the server, none were modified since 2014 in the js folder, but if you reckon i can re-ftp all the files ?

Comment: There might be a bigger problem: https://shoplift.byte.nl/scan/justfrompound.com/admin?

Comment: The error was due to conflict with an earlier installed extension.  I went to app/etc/modules/my_new_extension.xml - edit the file and marked it active "false" /active - so it would not load again.  Disable the compiler - ran the compiler again and viola - things sorted !  - thanks kevin anyway.